# How does the topology on the Quotient space look like?

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $S=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and consider 
$$
S^{\mathbb{Z}}=\{x=(\ldots,x_{-1},x_0,x_1,\ldots): x_k\in S~\forall~k\in\mathbb{Z}\}.
$$
The natural topology on $S$ is the discrete topology and on $S^{\mathbb{Z}}$ we consider product topology whose base are the cylinder sets
$$
C_t[a_0,\ldots,a_m]:=\{x\in S^{\mathbb{Z}}: x_t=a_0,\ldots,x_{t+m}=a_m\}.
$$
Moreover, let $\sigma\colon S^{\mathbb{Z}}\to S^{\mathbb{Z}}$ be the right-shift, i.e. $\sigma(x_i)=x_{i-1}$.

> > On $S^{\mathbb{Z}}$, consider the equivalence relation
> >     $$
> > x\sim y~\Leftrightarrow~x=\sigma^p(y)\text{ for some }p\in\mathbb{Z}.
> > $$
> >     That is, $x$ is equivalent to $y$ if $x$ is a shifted version of $y$ and vice versa.

Let $\pi\colon S^{\mathbb{Z}}\to S^{\mathbb{Z}}/\sim,~~x\mapsto [x]$ be the canonical projection.

On $S^{\mathbb{Z}}/\sim$, we consider the quotient topology, i.e.
$$
A\subseteq S^{\mathbb{Z}}/\sim\text{ open }~\Leftrightarrow~\pi^{-1}(A)\text{ open in }S^{\mathbb{Z}}.
$$

I would like to describe the open sets $A\subseteq S^{\mathbb{Z}}/\sim$ concretely. Since we know how the base in $S^{\mathbb{Z}}$ looks like, this should be possible.

------- Here is what I tried.

A set $A\subseteq S^{\mathbb{Z}}/\sim$ is open iff $\pi^{-1}(A)$ can be written as an union of cylinder sets since the cylinder seits form a base.

I think another useful lemma is that
$$
A\subseteq S^{\mathbb{Z}}/\sim\text{ open }~\Leftrightarrow~\bigcup_{[a]\in A}[a]\text{ is open in }S^{\mathbb{Z}}.
$$

> > So my idea is to find those $A\subseteq S^{\mathbb{Z}}/\sim$ for which
> >     $\bigcup_{[a]\in A}[a]$ can be written as an union of cylinder sets.

If I am not mistaken, I think for *each* $A\subseteq S^{\mathbb{Z}}/\sim$, we have that $\bigcup_{[a]\in A}[a]$ is at least contained in some open set, for example
$$
\bigcup_{[a]\in A}[a]\subseteq\bigcup_{[a]\in A}\bigcup_{p\in\mathbb{Z}}\{x\in S^{\mathbb{Z}}:(x_{-n},\ldots,x_n)=\sigma^p(a)_{[-n,n]}\}
$$
for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

But this does not really help...

Comment: $\sim$ as defined is not symmetric.  The verbal definition is not the same as the abstract definition and is wrong for using "and visa versa" when it should be "or visa versa".  Please make the necessary edits to correct those errors.

Comment: Maybe you can help me to formalize it correctly. What I mean is that $x$ and $y$ are considered to be equivalent, if $x$ is a shifted version of $y$, i.e. $x=\sigma^p(y)$ for some integer $p\in\mathbb{Z}$; then $y$ is also a shifted version of $x$, since $y=\sigma^{-p}(x)$.

Comment: You are right, I misread your definition.